# I get apache error

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Hi can you plese help me. I get an error on php apache and i dont't know how can i fix it. Error:

```
[Tue Jul 08 17:55:44 2014] [error] [client 192.168.*.*] File does not exist:
/var/www/name of server/servlet
[Tue Jul 08 17:55:46 2014] [error] [client 192.168.*.*] client denied by server
configuration: /var/www/name of server/server-status
[Tue Jul 08 17:55:46 2014] [error] [client 192.168.*.*] Invalid URI in request
GET @testasp.vulnweb.com/rpb.png HTTP/1.1
[Tue Jul 08 17:55:46 2014] [error] [client 192.168.*.*] Invalid URI in request
GET :@testasp.vulnweb.com/rpb.png HTTP/1.1
[Tue Jul 08 17:55:46 2014] [error] [client 192.168.*.*] Invalid URI in request
GET @testasp.vulnweb.com::80/rpb.png HTTP/1.1
[Tue Jul 08 17:55:46 2014] [error] [client 192.168.*.*] Invalid URI in request
GET :@testasp.vulnweb.com::80/rpb.png HTTP/1.1
[Tue Jul 08 17:55:47 2014] [error] [client 192.168.*.*] Invalid URI in request
GET /sdk/../../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Those errors are being caused by something scanning your server for common vulnerabilities - you can't really fix that, since getting scanned by stuff is a normal part of having a service on the internet.

If your system's well secured and up to date, this kind of scanning is nothing to worry about.